# Duplicate check of title when editing

Tags: discussion, etiquette

So I was about to edit a question title (shown in image 1) as it had incorrect spellings thinking that the user might have hastily written the title. But when I edited the title, it shouted me with the validation: "This question already exists, be more specific".

[image: Image1]

[image: Image 2]

This means the user stepped over the validation by making the title spellings incorrect instead of re-framing or specifically quoting the problem; I don't know whether he did that knowingly or unknowingly.

I brought this issue up here to raise the concern that If the validations can easily be stepped over and/or misused, then there is no way of ensuring the quality control and users entering proper data and having so much validations in the first place.

In general how should such behaviors be tackled? A flag, downvote, report or comment? How to ensure that purpose of validations are served and not just stepped over especially when such behaviors come from the users who are not considerably new and have repuations > 1k?

Comment: It is better to add that validation only when asking a question, but not editing it....

Comment: IMHO _"Why this code doesn't compile"_ is not a good title anyway. The title should describe the problem a bit more in detail...

Comment: Yes, that was just one example I bumped across. The point I want to make is that it was OP's duty to make a clear title instead of over stepping the validation by making the wrong and unclear title.

Comment: Downvote, vote to close as unclear.

Answer (score 5):

The title validation as well as comment/body of post validations are there to hint on desired behavior, and not a way to enforce particular behavior. Trying to prevent all possible variations of undesired content is prohibitively expensive and hence not implemented on SO (or really anywhere). Editing title is the best option to teach correct behavior. Definitely don't flag (as you can act on title yourself) unless you verified that the user actively rejects good title updates or ignores multiple comments suggesting to get better titles/posts in general (use custom flag with links to other questions).

If the title after your editing is duplicate that it is a good sign that the question is duplicate too. Please consider to act on whole question instead.

In this particular case edited title is simply <strike>not acceptable</strike> low quality. Such edit should be rejected (similarly to edits like spell-checking "thank you mach" which should be just removed instead). Better action would be either to come up with a title explaining the actual problem (if you believe the question worth your effort) or comment to OP about making a better title (possibly with downvote/close as unclear if post overall deserves it).